# Periodically automating updates on flexdashboard in R

Tags: r, plotly, flexdashboard

I have created a dashboard using the `flexdashboard` package in `R`. I am hoping to get some advice on two questions

1. Some of the data in my dashboard is extracted from online sources using plugins and would need to be updated on a daily basis. Is there a way in which I can automatically set my dashboard to update at a certain time of the day instead of always having to manually hit knit?
2. I have some `plotly` images embedded in my dashboard. Is there a way to add a feature in the `plotly` menu in which one can export the data from an image into excel format (similarly to how you can export each image as a png)?

Here is my YAML

```
---
title: "Macroeconomic Dashboard"
output: 
  flexdashboard::flex_dashboard:
    orientation: columns
    vertical_layout: fill
    logo: bon.png
---
```

and here is an example of a code chunk and data I have in my dashboard with a `plotly` image embedded in it

```
structure(list(Date = structure(c(18048, 18078, 18109, 18140, 
18170, 18201, 18231, 18262, 18293, 18322, 18353, 18383, 18414, 
18048, 18078, 18109, 18140, 18170, 18201, 18231, 18262, 18293, 
18322, 18353, 18383, 18414), class = "Date"), Key = c("Slate Balance", 
"Slate Balance", "Slate Balance", "Slate Balance", "Slate Balance", 
"Slate Balance", "Slate Balance", "Slate Balance", "Slate Balance", 
"Slate Balance", "Slate Balance", "Slate Balance", "Slate Balance", 
"Over/Underrecovery", "Over/Underrecovery", "Over/Underrecovery", 
"Over/Underrecovery", "Over/Underrecovery", "Over/Underrecovery", 
"Over/Underrecovery", "Over/Underrecovery", "Over/Underrecovery", 
"Over/Underrecovery", "Over/Underrecovery", "Over/Underrecovery", 
"Over/Underrecovery"), Value = c(46.18, 89.89, 18.17, 0, -33.01, 
-16.21, -17.63, -3.94, 44.65, 205.02, 188.88, 157.39, 2.29, 84.06, 
43.71, -71.72, -18.17, -33.01, 16.8, -1.41, 13.68, 48.59, 160.37, 
-16.14, -31.49, -155.1)), row.names = c(NA, -26L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"))
```

```
pacman::p_load(tidyverse,plotly)

p1 <- ggplot(slate, aes(Date, Value, fill=Key)) +
      geom_bar(data = slate %>% filter(Key=='Slate Balance'|Key=='Over/Underrecovery'),position='dodge', stat='identity') +
      scale_fill_manual(values = c('#75002B','#EFBE93')) +
      scale_x_date(breaks = seq(head(slate$Date, 1), 
                            tail(slate$Date, 1),
                            by = '2 months'), date_labels = '%b-%Y') +
      scale_y_continuous(breaks = seq(-400, 400, by = 50)) +
      labs(y='N$ Million') +
      theme(legend.title = element_blank()) +
      theme_bw() +
      geom_hline(yintercept=0, color = "red", linetype = 'dashed')


p1 %>% ggplotly(tooltip = c('Date','Value')) %>% 
       layout(legend = list(orientation = "h", x = 0.25, y = 1.1)) %>% 
       add_annotations(xref='paper',yref='paper',x=1,y=-0.09,text='*Source - Ministry of Mines and Energy',showarrow=F,
                  font=list(size=10,color='black'))
```

TIA!

Comment: I'm not sure if this works, one idea I have is to use `runtime: shiny`, make the data source reactive and use [`reactivePoll`](https://shiny.rstudio.com/reference/shiny/latest/reactivePoll.html) to update the data

Comment: @starja how would I be able to incorporate ```reactivePoll``` into my YAML?

Comment: you don't include it into your YAML but you have to rewrite your R functions in the markdown, have a look here at how to use shiny with flexdashboard: https://rmarkdown.rstudio.com/flexdashboard/shiny.html